# How to add exception for backup MX to tumgreyspf?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, mx-record

I have an Ubuntu raring server running postfix/dovecot as an email server, with tumgreyspf doing greylisting and SPF checks.

My problem is that I also have a backup MX server, that is supposed to store my emails temporarily, should my main server ever fails. It usually rejects receiving emails if it finds the main server online and functional.

The problem is when it does need to do its job, tumgreyspf rejects all emails from the backup MX with an error like this:

```
Jun 27 16:18:13 hamra postfix/smtpd[28732]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mxbackup.mydomain.com[x.x.x.x]: 550 5.7.1 <some_email@mydomain.com>: Recipient address rejected: QUEUE_ID="" SPF Reports: 'SPF fail - not authorized'; from=<someone@someone.org> to=<some_email@mydomain.com> proto=SMTP helo=<mxbackup.mydomain.com>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tumgreyspf README](https://github.com/linsomniac/tumgreyspf)

```
COMMON PROBLEMS

  SPF checks need to be bypassed for relays for the domain, such as
   secondary MX servers.  [...]

   One way of bypassing this check would be to ensure that MX servers are
   listed in mynetworks, and that permit_mynetworks is ahead of the call to
   tumgreyspf.
```